# Is asp.net used for web development only?

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is asp.net used for web development only?

Answer (score 6):

For ASP.Net - yes. For the language(s) and the .NET platform that often are used with them such as c# and vb.net, no.

Answer (score 1):

You could be using Web Services as one of the pieces of the whole solution being built/deployed.

So, I say no if you mean only to develop sites.

Answer (score -6):

Yes ASP.NET is for web development such as PHP is made for web development too both are interpreted programming langauges.

ASP.NET has less benefits as it can only be ran on windows operating systems hence why it's lessor use, as most hosts run on a linux os.

Well they made a new interpreter called Mono which allows you to run ASP.NET on linux but its longer to implement in the long run. As well as most cheap hosts will not allow you to install Mono and if you pick windows host it will be slightly more expensive.

Yet PHP is portable and made for mostly all operating systems including linux, windows and Mac OS

Doesn't mean you cannot use PHP to make executable applications without website interface, all thats really required is to pass your script onto the interpreter and it will give out a output for both ASP or PHP

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP. And ASP.NET is not an interpreted programming language. I think you're confusing it with Classic ASP.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure ASP.NET is in fact a interpreted. If it wasn't it wouldn't produce BYTECODE but actual assembly code which it doesn't. If you mean that ASP.NET has to be compiled that doesn't make it any less of a interpreted language. Thats like saying just because you can compile Java code to class file making it not interpreted yet it still is interpreted.

Comment: Java produces bytecode, but is considered to be compiled? Good point, I'm not sure how that's considered different than PHP with a bytecode cache.

Comment: ASP.NET web apps are NOT interpreted. Managed code is converted to bytecode/IL, and then JIT-compiled into native code. Classic ASP was interpreted ala PHP. Take a look at the "Features of the Common Language Runtime". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw4w595w%28VS.71%29.aspx and the CLI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language